System.InvalidOperationException happens in my WPF application
I am writing a WPF application following the MVVM pattern I have DataGrid in my view. I also have 4 textboxes, 1 combobox and a button to add new entity to my DataGrid. I am using Entity Framework Core to handle the data.
Here's the combobox:
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NewWorker.JobTitles}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding NewWorker.JobTitle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</ComboBox>

Worker class:
public class Worker : ObservableObject
{
     private int _id;
     private string _name;
     private string _secondName;
     private int _age;
     private string _email;
     private List<JobTitle> _jobTitles;

     private int _jobTitleId;
     private JobTitle? _jobTitle;

     public int Id 
     {
         get => _id;
         set => Set(ref _id, value); 
     }

     public string Name 
     { 
         get => _name; 
         set => Set(ref _name, value);
     }

     [NotMapped]
     public List<JobTitle> JobTitles
     {
         get => _jobTitles;
         set => Set(ref _jobTitles, value);
     }

     public int JobTitleId
     {
         get => _jobTitleId;
         set => Set(ref _jobTitleId, value);
     }

     public JobTitle? JobTitle
     {
         get => _jobTitle; 
         set => Set(ref _jobTitle, value);
     }
}

JobTitle class:
public class JobTitle : ObservableObject
{
    private int _id;
    private string _title;
    private ObservableCollection<Worker> _workers;

    public int Id 
    { 
        get => _id; 
        set => Set(ref _id, value); 
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => Set(ref _title, value);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
    {
        get => _workers; 
        set => Set(ref _workers, value);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return (obj==null || obj is not JobTitle) ? false : Title == (obj as JobTitle).Title;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Title.GetHashCode();
    }
}

View model for view with combobox:
public class WorkersDataTableVM : ObservableObject
{
    private WorkerRepository _workerRepository;
    private JobTitleRepository _jobTitleRepository;
    private ObservableCollection<Worker> _workers;
    private Worker _newWorker;

    public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
    {
        get => _workers;
        set => Set(ref _workers, value);
    }

    public Worker NewWorker
    {
        get => _newWorker;
        set => Set(ref _newWorker, value);
    }

    public RelayCommand AddWorkerCommand { get; set; }

    public WorkersDataTableVM() 
    {
        _workerRepository = new WorkerRepository();
        _jobTitleRepository = new JobTitleRepository();
        Workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>(_workerRepository.GetAllWorkers());
        NewWorker = new Worker();
        LoadData();
        AddWorkerCommand = new RelayCommand(AddWorker,CanAddWorker);
    }

     private bool CanAddWorker(object arg)
     {
         bool flag = false;

         if (NewWorker.Name != default(string) && NewWorker.SecondName != default(string) && NewWorker.Age != default(int) && NewWorker.JobTitleId != default(int))
         {
             flag = true;
         }

         return flag;
    }

    private void AddWorker(object obj)
    {
        Workers.Add(NewWorker);
        _workerRepository.AddWorker(NewWorker);
        NewWorker = new();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        var workers = _workerRepository.GetAllWorkers();
        var jobTitle = _jobTitleRepository.GetAllJopTitles();
        Workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>(workers);

        foreach (Worker worker in Workers)
        {
            worker.JobTitles = jobTitle;
        }

        NewWorker.JobTitles = jobTitle;
    }
}

I don't understand why I am getting this exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'JobTitle' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

I wrote a same simple console application that is doing the same thing:
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }     
    public Company? Company { get; set; }    
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; } 

    public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new();

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return (obj == null || obj is not Company) ? false : Name == (obj as Company).Name;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {  
            User user = new User();
            
            user.Companies = db.Companies.ToList();
            user.Name = "Name";
            user.Company = user.Companies[0];

            db.Users.Add(user);     
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

and this little program is working fine and without throwing exceptions.
PS: I tried to add new Worker using my code in VM but exception still happens, so I don't think the problem is in XAML part.
PS #2: I can fix it if i will create new worker using property JobTitleId instead of JobTitle, but then I will need to add converters to my combobox and so on.
Update: I understand that my problem is that I create more than one DbContext in my repository at the same time, and they are
interfering with each other, so my NEW question how should I fix it:

Should I create one common DbContext for all repositories which will exist over the whole lifecycle of the application

Or should I create a new DbContext every single time I need to execute CRUD operation?


Which is the more appropriate way in WPF and MVVM context?

Start off by ditching the Repository all-together. EF already provides a Repository in the form of the DbSet. Abstracting this with a Generic Repository (repository per entity) is an anti-pattern with EF and will gain you nothing but headaches, especially with WPF where you have to be explicit about lifetime scopes.
Next, when it comes to entities, avoid this:
 private List<JobTitle> _jobTitles;
 [NotMapped]
 public List<JobTitle> JobTitles
 {
     get => _jobTitles;
     set => Set(ref _jobTitles, value);
 }

Never expose setters to collection navigation properties. Initialize the list and keep the setter protected so only EF populates it:
 private List<JobTitle> _jobTitles = new();
 public List<JobTitle> JobTitles
 {
     get => _jobTitles;
     protected set { _jobTitles = value; }
 }

You never want code re-initializing a collection. Setting singular references is fine, that is how you tell EF to change the FK for an entity, but never collections. EF's change tracking will get messed up if you expose a public setter that gets called. "Cheats" like setting the collection to a new set to add/remove items doesn't work out well with EF. Explicitly add and remove items from the collection.
Next, when it comes to data binding in WPF with MVVM I highly recommend avoiding binding directly to entities. It can work, but you end up mixing EF concerns. (EF Proxy behaviour) with binding concerns (Observable) A ViewModel is not limited to serving the top level view (page) but can contain child view models to represent the fragment views of the data involved. For instance if you have a WorkersDataTableVM to serve a page listing all of the workers, you can have a collection of WorkerViewModel to represent each single worker and project the Worker entity to build a WorkerViewModel. View-related concerns stay in the view models, data concerns stay in the entities and entities can be flattened, transformed, formatted etc. as needed within the view model. In this way DbContext instances can remain short lived, alive solely long enough to load data projected to the ViewModels for the view bindings, then instantiated as needed to fetch entities to update based on the current state of the ViewModels when desired. Otherwise you are left leaving DbContext instances open so bindings back to the entities can be persisted (leaving the door open for poisoning if something messes up) and the memory/performance/stale data implications of long-lived DbContexts. Or you are staring down the rabbit hole of working with detached entities and dealing with concurrency issues, as well as potential reference tracking issues like what you are seeing.
Edit: For view model bindings, right now you have a view model for the form (WorkersDataTableVM) which contains entities:
public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers {get; set; }
public Worker NewWorker { get; set; }

Instead of using the Worker entity (which should be solely focused on data domain concerns) we create a WorkerVM view-model class. Where the Worker entity (not provided) would have things like navigation properties for its relationships and other data concerns, we don't need all of that for our view, so the WorkerVM can be a simplified representation that only concerned about what the view needs:
public class WorkerVM
{
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    // ... anything else the view actually needs.
}

For instance if a Worker has a reference to a Department entity but the view just needs the department name, Select can flatten this out:
 var workers = await Context.Workers
     .Where(w => w.Company.CompanyId == companyId)
     .Select(w => new WorkerVM 
     {
          WorkerId = w.WorkerId,
          Name = w.LastName + ", " + w.FirstName,
          DepartmentName = w.Department.Name
          // ...
     }).ToListAsync();

 var viewModel = new WorkersDataTableVM
 {
     Workers = workers
 };
 return View(viewModel);

Projecting in this way means we don't load and track entities and related entities that the view might want details for. It builds efficient queries that only return the fields that we request. This also means that when you go to pass worker details back to services from the view, you should be also working with these worker view-models. To update a worker your service code or APIs would accept the view model (either WorkerVM, or a purpose-built CreateWorkerVM / UpdateWorkerVM etc.) then fetch a tracked entity from a DbContext instance, copy values across, and call SaveChanges. Copying values across can be done manually or with the help of a mapper.
This may seem unnecessary compared to just passing the entity in the first place but there are several issue with passing and binding to entities. Firstly, if you want related data like a Department.Name you would need to ensure that the Department is eager loaded with Worker or it would be #null or tripping a lazy load call. Loading an entity will pull all fields, even if your view does not need them. If the DbContext gets disposed then those entities are now detached which brings in more complications if you want to send those entities back and use them to update the database again. A view model also serves as a great place for any view/user business logic such as data formatting, validation rules, etc.

I apologize for possibly stupid questions, but if i need to create new Entity (and my setter is proteced) how can i fulfill my collection? using .add() for each item i want to add?
And i dont really understand about wrapping my Worker class into its single ViewModel. I should do something like this :
` WorkersDataTableVM{ List list}
WorkerViewModel {Worker worker}`
if the answer is yes i dont really understand how i should bind it and why is it better way

Yes, the collection is initialized so you use Add() or pass the Enumerable initial set into a public constructor, leaving a protected default constructor for EF.  ViewModels are just plain C# objects so these don't need any special considerations beyond binding and they can handle things like formatting. EF supports projecting entities into other classes via Select, and mappers like Automapper/Mapperly etc. support it as well via methods like ProjectTo.

I expanded on the answer to show how projection would work with the entities.
